# Rearrange Flatlist items without reload React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm looking for rearrange Flatlist items without refresh the Flatlist/reload in React Native
just like the Chat Applications, when you receive new message from someone down in the list, this person will be the first one on the list.

i have searched a lot and all i could find was adding, removing, drag & drop sortable.
i'm looking for it to happen automatically when the user receive a message that message will be the first on the list.

all the code i have for now is flatlist with dummy data

now lets say i want the id 3 to be number 1 without refresh/reload the flatlist, i know i should be using Animation but im not strong in animation RN.

```
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];

function Item({ title }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});
```

Comment: if you use ```react-native-firebase``` as your database, you can use function ```ref.on()``` where it will listens to your changes and update it automatically

Comment: @displayname listening to changes is not a problem, i have socket on the backend, the problem is when the new results come in or when the values changes, the list will refresh/reload specially on android.